# Compare passwords in PHPBB3 and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, phpbb3

This is the case:

I am trying to compare the password given in a form made by myself with the password already exist in the database and that was created by the `phpbb`.

So:

*1. Password of course is hashed in mysql database*

*2. Use `password_hash()`*

What I think should work:

```
$match = password_verify( (password_hash($userpass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)), $row[3] );
```

phpbb can actually hash the plain text and get the same hash is stored in the database so, how to get the same functionality?

Comment: Pretty sure phpBB uses PHPass which has a salt, so this simply will not work. One would think a `username` would be unique though, so no need for selecting on the password. Also you may have an SQL injection vulnerability there.

Comment: In this case is mandatory so anyone who knows your username can't access with your credentials. Password is needed

Comment: Then check the password after selecting the user. That you can do.

Comment: There is when I come to the case: passwords stored in the database are encrypted somehow...

Comment: Hashed, not encrypted. You can verify if a hash is a password, using [`phpbb_check_hash`](https://wiki.phpbb.com/Function.phpbb_check_hash) or PHPass (assuming phpBB does use PHPass, as I think it does).

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact ins and outs, but phpBB passwords are definitely salted so the same password on different boards will have different hashes.